# Dependency Property not changing the binded Value (MVVM-Helper)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just can't find the missing piece. My UserControl doesn't update the binded property. I'm creating a new UserControl in my code behind. The SetValue and GetValue method are getting called. If the viewModel is initializing some value, my UserControl gets it. But if I change the text in the Textbox, the viewmodel doesn't hold this value.

My Code:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

       public MyUserControl()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public static readonly DependencyProperty CommentToAddProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register(
         nameof(CommentToAdd),
         typeof(string),
         typeof(MyUserControl),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
          default(string),
          FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
          OnCommentChange));


    public string CommentToAdd
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(CommentToAddProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommentToAddProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnCommentChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var myUC = d as MyUserControl;
        var comment = e.NewValue as string;
        myUC.CommentToAdd = comment;
        myUC.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CommentToAdd));
}

public partial class SomeWindow: Window
{
   public SomeWindow()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     _vm = new MyViewModel();
     DataContext = _vm;
     var userControl = new UserControls.MyUserControl
     {
        CommentToAdd = _vm.CommentToAdd,  
     }

     \\Add usercontrol to a grid
   }

   
}

public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   private string _commentToAdd;
}
```

This is my XAML code in my UserControl

```
<TextBox
    Grid.Column="0"
    Text="{Binding Path= CommentToAdd, Mode=TwoWay, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        Mode=FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType=local:MyUserControl},  
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: "the viewmodel doesn't hold this value" - there is no binding between viewmodel and usercontrol. only binding between usercontrol and textbox is defined

Comment: CommentToAdd = _vm.CommentToAdd. I thought with this, i set the dependency property. And if the dependency is calling SetValue(...) it should be updated.

Comment: First of all, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in a class derived from DependencyObject is pointless. Dependency property already provide their own change notification mechanism. Also the rest of the OnCommentChange callback is pointless, since you are only assigning a value that the property already has.

Comment: "with this, i set the dependency property" - yes, you set the DP value. once. TextBox will recieve it. but it is not binding. if you change textBox text via typing it will not be propagated back to view model

Comment: @Clemens Yes, i try things out currently :(. I thought the OnCommentChange is not necessary aswell, but i just try to pass the value to my ViewModel Property

Comment: @ASh but it should be possible, that my usercontroll changes the property in my viewmodel right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment

```
CommentToAdd = _vm.CommentToAdd
```

does not establish a data binding of the CommentToAdd property.

In order to create a Binding, you would have to write

```
userControl.SetBinding(
    MyUserControl.CommentToAddProperty,
    new Binding("CommentToAdd"));
```

or without relying on the assigned DataContext and on the fact that the property binds TwoWay by default

```
userControl.SetBinding(
    MyUserControl.CommentToAddProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        Source = _vm,
        Path = new PropertyPath("CommentToAdd"),
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    });
```

However, you should usually not be creating UI elements in code behind. Better declare the control in XAML:

```
<MyUserControl CommentToAdd="{Binding CommentToAdd}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the binding of the `MyUserControl.CommentToAdd` property to the `MyViewModel.CommentToAdd` property.

The property changed callback in the `UserControl` is not required and should be removed.

Controls, or `DependencyObject` types in general, must not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Dependency properties already have their change notification. And because dependency properties provide better performance, they have precedence over `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the binding engine will ignore the interface in favor of the dependency property.
`INotifyPropertyChanged` is only relevant for types that need to participate in the framework's binding infrastructure but do not extend `DependencyObject` (and implement the source properties as dependency properties).

**MyUserControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
  public MyUserControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty CommentToAddProperty= DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(CommentToAdd),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    default(string),
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));


  public string CommentToAdd
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(CommentToAddProperty);
    set => SetValue(CommentToAddProperty, value);
  }
}
```

**SomeWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class SomeWindow: Window
{
  public SomeWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
 
    _vm = new MyViewModel();
    DataContext = _vm;
  }   
}
```

**SomeWindow.xaml.**

```xml
<Window>
  <MyUserControl CommentToAdd="{Binding CommentToAdd}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes my code is pretty much garbage, because i tried so many different things. I'll clean up now :)

Comment: You are funny :D I understand that code can get quickly messed up while you are desperately trying to fix misbehaving code. Then have a good time cleaning up.